# Using ganymed-ssh2 >> getting error "Authentication method password not supported by the server at this stage"

Tags: java, authentication

I am using ganymed-ssh2 to carry out remote execution of commands provided in a xml config file. It works fine for most of the servers except for some where i am getting the following error.

> java.io.IOException: Password authentication failed. at
>   ch.ethz.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePassword(AuthenticationManager.java:300)
>   at
>   ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection.authenticateWithPassword(Connection.java:309)
>   at
>   GenericAccessOnly.GenericAccessOnly.Access(GenericAccessOnly.java:260)
>   at
>   GenericAccessOnly.GenericAccessOnly.main(GenericAccessOnly.java:190)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Authentication method password not
>   supported by the server at this stage. at
>   ch.ethz.ssh2.auth.AuthenticationManager.authenticatePassword(AuthenticationManager.java:270)
>   ... 3 more

Any help in this regard will certainly of great help.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well.. The exception really speaks for itself, doesn't it? The server in question simply does not support password authentication. You should implement code that tries different authentication approaches supported by ganymed-ssh2.

There is example code included in ganymed-ssh2, which explains how to check available auth methods. Example:

```java
if (connection.isAuthMethodAvailable(getUsername(), "publickey")) {
    System.out.println("--> public key auth method supported by server");
} else {
    System.out.println("--> public key auth method not supported by server");
}
if (connection.isAuthMethodAvailable(getUsername(), "keyboard-interactive")) {
    System.out.println("--> keyboard interactive auth method supported by server");
} else {
    System.out.println("--> keyboard interactive auth method not supported by server");
}
if (connection.isAuthMethodAvailable(getUsername(), "password")) {
    System.out.println("--> password auth method supported by server");
} else {
    System.out.println("--> password auth method not supported by server");
}
```

Here are the [examples](https://code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fexamples). Take a look at [SwingShell](https://code.google.com/p/ganymed-ssh-2/source/browse/trunk/examples/SwingShell.java) which uses more than just password auth.